# Why my reputation has gone down when I can't see any negative rep's

Tags: support, reputation

In stack overflow yesterday I've gained 4more points which gave me over 1900 but soon after it was reverted to 1898 but on the rep list I can see only positive reps including those 4points which should give me over 1900.

Comment: Check the box next to "show removed posts" all the way at the bottom of your reputation history.

Comment: Well that is a master of disguise, like a navy seal:) it should be at the top.

Comment: The placement was designed when deleted questions were more of a rarity, I believe...

Comment: one way or another if it affects the reputation it should be either turned on by default or placed in more visible place:)

Comment: The current system is completely broken and confusing anyways: [Separate and visually indicate reversed events from the day's reputation changes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146682/separate-and-visually-indicate-reversed-events-from-the-days-reputation-changes)